# The GPU usage provided by nvidia-smi command is very different from GPU metrics from guest OS

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vcenter, nvidia, task-manager, gpu

I'm working on a project that can monitor virtual machines' vgpu usage.
The hypervisor is `vCenter`, we have nvidia A16 cards installed on vCenter hosts, and assigned a16 vGPU to a couple of windows VMs on this host, theses vGPUs are allocated to the same GPU chip.

I tried to use `nvidia-smi` command to retrieve vGPU usage in both the host and VMs.
In host I used `nvidia-smi vgpu`, and in VMs I used `nvdia-smi`.
But it turned out the metrics provided by nvidia-smi was always different from what was provided by Windows OS in VM.

For example, the usage from `nvidia-smi` could be as low as **6%**, but the usage from windows task manager was always around **15%**.

[image]

We prefer to trust the metrics provided by guest OS, as it reflects the real demand of user case.

My question is, what's the meaning and source of nvidia-smi metrics? Why is the result so different? Can I somehow modify the result to reflect the real guest demand?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The periods and/or timepoints during/at which Task Manager and nvidia-smi measure might be different, which leads to different usage percentages.

As per the [documentation](https://enterprise-support.nvidia.com/s/article/Useful-nvidia-smi-Queries-2)

> utilization.gpu
>
> Percent of time over the past sample period during which one or more kernels was executing on the GPU.
> The sample period may be between 1 second and 1/6 second depending on the product.

> utilization.memory
>
> Percent of time over the past sample period during which global (device) memory was being read or written.
> The sample period may be between 1 second and 1/6 second depending on the product.

Try a constant non-changing load and measure then if they match.

Comment: Hi Raf, thanks for he response! 
What confused me was, sometimes one of the vGPU utilization is 0, and the other vGPU is high. Our guest load is always there, so there is no way to be 0. I feel that this 0 comes from the real time slice assigned to a vGPU, instead of the utilization it virtualized to be?

Comment: I don't know how to interpret your question, "I feel that this 0 comes from the real time slice assigned to a vGPU, instead of the utilization it virtualized to be?". As far as I read your question right, `nvidia-smi vgpu` on host and `nvidia-smi` on guest do yield the same results? I would rather trust nvidia-smi than task manager though (also how would you read out task manager programatically?).